# Is it worth to be a co-author in a conference paper abstract?

Tags: conference, authorship, abstract

If I cooperate as the second author of a conference paper abstract, can it be mentioned in a cv?

Comment: Your question in the title and body are different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is fine for your CV as long as it is described accurately. Not a major item in every case but positive.

Your CV should show that you are intellectually active, but collaboration is also a positive point. And, the abstract may develop into a full paper, I assume.